# How to access user information in a ReactJS SPA application?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, single-page-application, user-data

How i can store user information in a ReactJS SPA application?

Let me explain, I have a REST API which sends me a cookie when connecting. It can be a sessionID or a JWT.
I would like to retrieve the information of the user linked to this cookie (email, name, roles...) and have access to it in my ReactJS application in order to display the data in the interface or to allow or not the display of components.
How can I do without having to call my server each time to retrieve this information?

I don't know how applications manage to access information without storing it...

I try everything even chatGPT so I expect someone to help me to solve this problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "each time"?

Comment: when there is a route change or an event that modifies the components

Comment: I may not have understood how authentication works and the link of it between the frontend and the backend in which case I would very much like an explanation

Comment: Can't you just store the user info in a variable?

Comment: yes but how it works if the user close the tab and come back on the application?

Comment: @Henri The answer where users write their own way of understanding authentication will be considered opinion-based, since it's not a focused question you'd have to do your own research & decide yourself. But in this post did you ask how to retrieve a cookie? If that's what you're asking for I'd write a function in the answer, but I prefer localStorage bcuz its simple setting a value `localStorage.setItem('token','tokenValue')` and retrieving:`localStorage.getItem('token')`. However you said "*without having to call my server*" but that's the point of having a server - to validate user token.

Comment: I only want to call my server for my authentication and get the informations. However I don't want to store them in the localStorage because user can edit easily. I would like to be readonly...

Comment: They can edit cookie as well, and why would an authenticated user want to log himself out by editing his auth-token rather than clicking "logout" ? Maybe you meant you want `httpOnly` cookie set by your backend, then you can't retrieve it using JavaScript but users may still edit their own cookie.

Comment: That said, there's no such thing as read-only cookie unless you want build your own browser. For every protected route/page lets say you are using Axios to make HTTP request with options `withCredentials: true` will send the user cookies to your backend and verify the user and either return the data or an error "Not allowed".

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an API, or the user info endpoint of an authorization server, to get the user info. Then store it in memory, and render it when required. This is also a secure and reliable option, eg saving personally identifiable information such as names and emails to local storage is not recommended.

The user can then navigate across views without needing to call the API again. Your path or hash based routing will take care of that. These user actions will cause the entire SPA to reload though, meaning the API will be called again, which is pretty standard behaviour:

- Reload page
- Open new browser tab

For an example, here is a [user info view](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/demoapp/src/views/userInfo/userInfoView.tsx) in a demo app of mine. Once rendered, the user info request does not run again. You can even run my [online demo app](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) to get a feel for how this performs.